# Double annihilator for subspaces of $E^*$: counter example.

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

In a topological vector space $E$, given $S \subset E$, let
$$
  S^\perp = \{ \phi \in E^* \mid \forall x \in S,\,\phi(x) = 0 \}.
$$
And for $F \subset E^*$, where $E^*$ is the dual space for $E$, let
$$
  F_\perp = \{ x \in E \mid \forall \phi \in F,\,\phi(x) = 0 \}.
$$

In Pedersen's *Analysis Now*, paragraph 2.3.6, we have the following comment:
(with the above notation)

> It is immediate that $S \subset (S^\perp)_\perp$,
>   and it follows from 2.3.5 that actually $S = (S^\perp)_\perp$
>   if $S$ is a closed subspace.
>   By contrast, we cannot expect that $F = (F_\perp)^\perp$
>   for every norm closed subspace $F$ of $E^*$.

I would like a counter example! :-)

I mean, I'd like a Banach space $E$ and a norm closed subspace $F \subset E^*$ such that
$$
F \subsetneq (F_\perp)^\perp.
$$

Comment: It seems I just want a norm closed $F$ that is not $w^*$-closed.

Comment: If we take any non-reflexive Banach space and embed in it's second dual by  canonical embedding (E). By Goldstein theorem that non-reflexive Banach space will be $weak^*$ dense in second dual. As it is non-reflexive, X and $X^{**}$ are not same. So X is norm closed but not $weak^*$ closed. E.g, $l^1$.

Comment: Here you get your desired counter example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799291/example-of-n-subseteq-e-such-that-n-perp-perp-neq-overlinen